# Eroding Text to from blobs OpenCV

Tags: c++, ios, opencv

I need to detect text blocks on a document and get back their bounding boxes, I have heard that I should erode the image which will "smudge" the text together and form blobs, then I can use blob detection to find where the text is. Currently I have I binarized image with some text on it.

I have been using this code to erode, and it is slightly merging the text together. But how can I make it more severe? The parameters have me slightly confused and if someone could explain how I could make the erosion harsher that would be great!

`erode(quad, quad, Mat(), cv::Point(-1, -1), 2, 1, 1);`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use larger structuring element:

```
int element_size=10;
Mat element = getStructuringElement( cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE,Size( 2*element_size + 1, 2*element_size+1 ),Point( element_size, element_size ) );
cv::erode(quad,quad,element);
```

I also think that this link will be useful for your task:

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/objdetect/doc/erfilter.html

Comment: I needed to up `element_size` but I know how to use it now! Thanks!